# FIND_IN_SET universal symbol?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create query like this:

```
$get_products = "SELECT P.*, C.`category_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(`category_name` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `cat` 
                   FROM `products` P 
                   NATURAL JOIN 
                     `categories` C 
                   NATURAL JOIN 
                     `product_to_categories`";
                   WHERE 
                     FIND_IN_SET(`category_name`, :selected_categories) 
                     AND `product_price` BETWEEN :price_min AND :price_max 
                  GROUP BY `product_name` 
                  ORDER BY 1 DESC ";
               
$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare($get_products);
$stmt -> bindValue(selected_categories, $selected_categories);
$stmt -> bindValue(price_min, $price_min);
$stmt -> bindValue(price_max, $price_max);
```

the problem is that string **$selected_categories** in some cases is empty, and when it is empty obviously nothing is found. 
Is there any parameter which I can use (for example `$selected_categories = '*';`) and it will cause that FIND_IN_SET will find everything?
or should I create completely new query for case when **$selected_categories** is empty?

Comment: What is `$selected_categories`? A string, or array? Also all your bindValue should be throwing php warnings about undefined constant use, using literal instead etc.

Comment: `$selected_categories` is a string. When is empty there is also problem with bindValue. This is the reason that I am looking for kind of symbol means "search for any"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable to reference the same replacement parameter twice:

```
 WHERE IF((@selected_categories:=:selected_categories)='*',1,FIND_IN_SET(category_name,@selected_categories))
```

and test some value you want to mean all ('*' in this example, you could use ='' or IS NULL or something else).

Some prefer using the SQL standard CASE instead of IF; that would look like:

```
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN (@selected_categories := :selected_categories) = '*' THEN 1
        ELSE FIND_IN_SET(category_name, @selected_categories)
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with simple logic

```
WHERE 
(
   :selected_categories = '*' OR
   FIND_IN_SET(`category_name`, :selected_categories) 
)
AND `product_price` BETWEEN :price_min AND :price_max
```

Comment: For some reason I was under the impression that the :keywords for replacement, couldn't be repeated in the same sql statement... or maybe its just the versions I've worked with was disabled to allow that.

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately your suggestion is not working, I have the impression similar to IncredibleHat

Comment: @Eisenheim: Is the value of `:selected_categories` either `*` or is it `null` or `''`?